# Styling of html in SharePoint Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, html

[image]

This is an html form that I have uploaded in document library and then added the link to content editor webpart. The CSS Like the colors and all that I have provided in the actual form is not working but the spacing and all is working fine on the SharePoint Webpage.
The below is the image of actual html.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank You in advance

Comment: You need to override some of the CSS with yours by applying `!important`. That's how it works in SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint applies most of the styles as regular css styles (only some of them are applied directly to the element as a style attribute). In order to override them you have to provide more accurate selectors then default SharePoint selectors. It may be difficult to achieve in some situation, so you can use !important to override them.

Comment: What selectors shall I use here?

Comment: If you have applied your custom css and controls do not look like you wanted to, you can run developer tools in chrome and check each element. Styles panel will show you which styles are applied and what selectors are related with them. Based on that you can create more specific selectors

Comment: see/learn: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/